# Implementation of sorting in Vector

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, adapter

I have a Collection as

```
Vector<HashMap<String, String>>
```

Actually I am using this as list items of list view in android.I used `SortedMap` but I did not get correct result. I think this is because HashMap's structure is

```
hashMap.add("Name","value_of_name"); 
hashMap.add("Counts","value_of_counts");
```

Now I am adding it to Vector.

I want to sort vector's element by `Name` key of hashMap.
I know about `Collection.sort` and I can sort this using ArrayList and POJO class. But I do not know how to use it with `adapter` of my `ListView`

How can I sort elements. And is there any better solution (Regarding my data-structure of collection, which can be use with adapter easily) ?

Comment: you'll need to be more precise in the description of your problem. are you trying to sort the vector or the contents of the hashmaps? what have you tried so far? how is the result supposed to be stored?

Comment: I don't get it, one hash map can have several keys. What is the criterion for one hash map to be placed before another?

Comment: A HashMap can have many keys (that's the whole point), and they could all even have the exact same keys, so you need to be more specific about how to sort the Vector

Comment: Vector is a legacy class which is like ArrayList, except synchronized.  Using sort is not thread safe and I suspect you don't need it to be so use ArrayList. If you need it to be thread safe, you should lock the Vector before sorting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the maps in the array, use a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementation like [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).  This takes a vector of HashMaps and returns a [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (a non-synchronized and faster collection than Vector) of SortedMaps.

```
public ArrayList<SortedMap<String, String>> sortMaps(Vector<HashMap<String, String> maps) {
    ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>> returnMaps = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> theMap : maps) {
        // TreeMap is a sorted map and this will use the default String.compareTo
        TreeMap<String, String> newMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        // put all the items from the HashMap into the TreeMap, which will autosort
        newMap.putAll(theMap);
        returnMaps.add(newMap);
    }
    return returnMaps;
}
```

To sort the Vector by the first keys (lowest keys, first alphabetically) of the hash map try the following before the return line:

```
    // this sorts the vector by first keys
    Collections.sort(returnMaps, new Comparator<SortedMap<String,String>>() {
        public int compare(SortedMap<String,String> a, HashMap<String,String> b) {
            return a.firstKey().compareTo(b.firstKey());
        }
    });
```

Or if you want to sort by last key (highest keys, last alphabetically):

```
    // this sorts the vector by first keys
    Collections.sort(returnMaps, new Comparator<SortedMap<String,String>>() {
        public int compare(SortedMap<String,String> a, HashMap<String,String> b) {
            return a.lastKey().compareTo(b.lastKey());
        }
    });
```

To return one sorted map of all keys (will stomp on any duplicates):

```
public SortedMap<String, String> singledSortedMap(Vector<HashMap<String, String> maps) {
    // this will end up with all the values, sorted by natural string ordering
    SortedMap<String, String> returnMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    for(HashMap<String, String> theMap : maps) {
        returnMap.putAll(theMap);
    }
    return returnMap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to a implement a `Comparator<HashMap<String,String> >` and place the logic of your sort ordering inside its `compare` method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand correctly. This will sort the vector on one key of the maps.

```
Collections.sort(yourVector, new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>() {
    public int compare(HashMap<String,String> a, HashMap<String,String> b) {
        return a.get(yourKey).compareTo(b.get(yourKey));
    }
});
```

Comment: Like aioobe said, you're assuming a single key "yourKey" for the hashmap? What's the point of the hashmap?

Comment: I'm not. I'm only assuming that the sorting is done on one particular key.

Answer (score 1):

Have you never thought about taking a look at collections in java.util package ?

You would then have discovered that [`Treemap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) already implements balanced tree sorting for [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) items, like String is.

So, to have your items sorted, just repalce your `HashMap` with a `TreeMap`, and all the work will be done.

BTW what does this vector does here ? They're sooo Java 1.1 (fifteen years old, in other words)

Answer (score 0):

The best (fastest) way it to use a TreeMap instead. If you supply it with the correct Comperator all the items in the TreeMap will be sorted.

The important question: Why do you have a Vector of HashMaps?

Comment: I can not change my data structure. Its requirement.